# Loop through column of r dataframe and pair records next to each other

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of words used in a speech and I'd like to count the number of times certain words are paired together. The words are in the right order so I just need to loop through the column and pair each word with the one before it.

Starting with

```
order | word
------------
1     | hello    
------------
2     | my
------------
3     | name    
------------
4     | is
```

Desired output would be something like this:

```
order | word | pair
--------------------
1     | hello| hello     
--------------------
2     | my   | hello my
--------------------
3     | name | my name  
--------------------
4     | is   | name is
```

Thanks in advance StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the last 'word' (`word[-length(word)]`), and first word (`word[-1]`), `paste` it together can concatenate with the first element to create the 'pair' column.

```
df1$pair <- with(df1, c(word[1], paste(word[-length(word)], word[-1])))
df1$pair
#[1] "hello"    "hello my" "my name"  "name is"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lag` function from the `Hmisc` package

```
library(Hmisc)
df$pair <- with(df, paste(Lag(word), word))
df$pair

# [1] " hello"   "hello my" "my name"  "name is"
```